# Google Calendar API Push Notifications - Event Moves into the Past

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working on an app which allows users to confirm they attended a google calendar event. I'd like them to make the confirmation immediately after the end time of the event.

Will subscription to Google's event push notifications (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) let me know when the event is over?

If not, what's the best way to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notifications only let you know about changes on the calendar (someone moved the event, someone responded etc.). There are no push notifications at starts and ends of events.
You can still combine storing the events and watching the changes to them with having a cron job (or similar) to run your code when events end.